# A interesting and a bold chess puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, chess, checkerboard

Here is a chess puzzle I have made . It needed a lot of thinking .

[image]

If you are white , how would you play in this position ? State your best moves !!

Please don't use Stockfish or Alphazero or any chess engine to answer this , if you definitely don't want to ruin the puzzle :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would play

> 1. Rc8+  Then 1... Kxc8 2. Qd8# or 1... Ka7 2. Qb6+ Bxb6 3. axb6+ Kxb6 4. Be3#

Comment: After Qb6 what?

Comment: Hey , it was quick , you are correct (I suppose you didn't use stockfish).

Comment: No, i didn't use any computer assistance :)  I didn't even set up the position, which is why i didn't have the full solution at first.  Nice problem, though :)